# Firefox Extension display image in document

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Is it possible to display local image in current document without violating the security constraints.

Example: image is in `chrome://myExtension/content/2.png`

`$myImg=jQuery("#myImg", doc);`

`$myImg.attr("src","chrome://beSure/content/2.png");`

> Error Console: Security Error: Content at https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?....&from=login may not load or link to chrome://myExtension/content/2.png.

Working example with non-local link:

`$myImg=jQuery("#myImg", doc);`

`myImg.attr("src","http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-cars-by-cemagraphics/128/minicar_128.png");`

Image comes from valid url so that is ok. But how can i display local image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chrome package needs to be declared with the `contentAccessible` flag in the `chrome.manifest`, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration#contentaccessible). By default, web pages are no longer allowed to load images from `chrome://`, this previously allowed web pages to detect installed extensions by loading their images.

The other possibility should be using `image.src` property instead of setting the attribute:

```
var myImg = doc.getElementById("myImg");
myImg.src = "chrome://beSure/content/2.png";
```

This should work because here your (privileged) script is setting image location directly. Attribute changes on the other hand are processed asynchronously, so this is done with the privileges of the web page.

Comment: I thought about it before and tried setting `.src` property but it didn't work. What i needed was your first suggestion, setting `contentAccessible` flag to `yes`. I read about it briefly while i was updating my extensions but i missed it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new element with jQuery be sure to use the right context as well.

```
var $tr = $('tr', content.document);
$tr.append($('<td>New cell</td>')); // BAD
```

will work but the new cell will behave strangely. For example you will get no context menu when you right-click in it.

To fix this use the document's context when creating new DOM nodes

```
$tr.append($('<td>New cell</td>', content.document)); // GOOD
```

By doing so you can use `chrome://`-URLs as you intended.
Of course you also have to enable `contentAccessible` as stated in Wladimir Palant's answer.