# inserting image into a webpage using firefox and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I am currently developing a Firefox extension and would like to display an image on a webpage pulled from my local extension directory. Unfortunately, firefox doesn't let me do that. It does not show any error messages and works fine if I request an image from an external resource.

Before asking, I tried to implement the solutions proposed here: [Firefox Extension display image in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188842/firefox-extension-display-image-in-document).
Unfortunately with no joy...

My code:

```
var $myImg=jQuery("#myImg", window.content.document);
$myImg.attr("src","chrome://plugin/content/agent.png");
    ...     
var jb = $jq("*", window.content.document)
.filter(function() {
if (this.src !== undefined) {
return this.src.match(regex);})
.replaceWith($myImg);
```

Let me know if more information is needed so I will add it to this description.

Comment: It looks ok now. I just declared image differently and it worked. 
`var img = '<img id="img1" src ="chrome://plugin/content/agent.png" />';`

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok now. I just declared image differently and it worked.

`var img = '<img id="img1" src ="chrome://plugin/content/agent.png" />';`